# Unable to remove a user in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g

I have a streams replication  related user in Oracle 11g. I see the user in dba_users table and was anle to login using the user but when I try to drop the user i get the error.

```
SQL> drop user <username> cascade;  
Error at line 1:  
ORA-1403: no data found.
```

Loos like data got corrupted in internal tables.

Any idea how to fix this mess and remove the user?

Comment: `drop user cascade;` isn't the correct Oracle syntax: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d09cbaeab922e1a351b18f5707250096

Comment: I ran drop user <username> cascade. My original comment was editied. Ex: drop user rep cascade.

Comment: Your original comment has been formatted, anything has changed: https://dba.stackexchange.com/revisions/202414/1 You can redo the review if you're not satisfied.

Comment: my point is that if it's been edited how do we know the error isn't edited too? It's helpful to see the *exact* command and output that ran, or at least make redactions clear. You wouldn't normally get an ORA-1403 at a SQL*Plus prompt

Comment: does the user you're logged into have the DROP USER permission?

Comment: I have logged in as sysdba to drop this user.

Answer (score 1):

The `ORA-01403` seems to indicate that you have a System Event Trigger for DROP USER.

You'll need to hunt down the appropriate trigger.

```
SELECT *
from dba_triggers
where base_object_type like 'DATABASE%'
and triggering_event like 'DROP%'
and status='ENABLED'
;
```

If that doesn't work, then I recommend that you open a ticket with Oracle Support.

Comment: Can you please explain more in detail as to what to do and how to fix the error. I see a trigger for the above query in dba_ triggers table.

Answer (score -2):

Check te user exist:

```
select * from all_users
```

or

```
select * from dba_users;
```

and see if exist or no.

Comment: The user exists in both the tables all_users and dba_users.